# using string_view to look up in unordered_map

Tags: c++, string, unordered-map, string-view

Say the following code:

```
unordered_map<string, int> test_map;
string_view fake_str = "Mike";
test_map[fake_str]; // does not work. No viable overloaded operator[] for type...
test_map.at(fake_str); // works.
```

I think the purpose of `string_view` is to reduce copy when passing string to function right?

And `[]` is also a function. Why I cannot pass string_view to `[]`?

Thank you!

Comment: With C++20, this will be possible through the `find()` member function given a little setup: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find

Comment: As of 2021-04-13 the example on unordered_map seems to **only** function on `gcc-trunk` and `clang trunk`. So it seems that it isn't fully implemented in released versions?

Answer (score 1):

Both `test_map[fake_str]` and `test_map.at(fake_str)` are not working: https://godbolt.org/z/EoP7bM

```
T& operator[]( const Key& key );
T& operator[]( Key&& key );
T& at( const Key& key );
const T& at( const Key& key ) const;
```

The Key type is `std::string`, that does not have implicit constructor from `std::string_view` by the exact reason as you said: "to reduce copy when passing string to function".

See the
[std::basic_string constructor (10)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) reference, look at the keyword `explicit`.

```
template < class T >
explicit basic_string( const T& t, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

template < class T >
explicit constexpr basic_string( const T& t,
                                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Comment: I don't really understand the constructor above.
I know the ```explicit``` means that no implicit conversion from "char" to "basic_string<char>". How is that related to my problem? Thx! :)

Comment: No implicit converting constructor from string_view to string exist. If it would exist then unneeded copy would be performed. String can't be constructed from string_view, thus `std::string& operator[]( const std::string& key )` is not viable.